# jQuery UI Sortable - запретить увеличение страницы при переносе блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Если взять сортируемый элемент и начать тянуть вниз/вбок страницы - страница будет бесконечно увеличиваться, пока элемент не будет отпущен.

Как запретить такое поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У jquery ui sortable есть такое замечательное свойство, как [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment). С помощью него можно ограничить перемещение элемента. В вашем случае должен быть элемент шириной и высотой равный размеру экрана.

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed",
    containment: ".demo"
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; cursor:move; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
#sortable li.fixed{cursor:default; color:#959595; opacity:0.5;}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
    
</div>
```